# net suite how to pass custom field data using phpToolKit_2013_1

Tags: php, xml, web-services, response, netsuite

I am new to netSuite trying to pass customer data into custom fields(Business Type, Customer Market, Regions) using web service but getting error in xml response.

If anybody has Idea, Please help in php script

Following is the script and xml response.

Script:

```
        <?

    require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

    $service = new NetSuiteService();
    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->lastName = "Amit";
    $customer->firstName = "Rathi";
    $customer->companyName = "xxxxxxx.xxx";
    $customer->phone = "123456789";
    $customer->email = "xxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx";


$labName                            = new StringCustomFieldRef();
$labName->internalId                = "custevent12"; // internal id of the input in Netsuite
$labName->value         = "USA East"; // your input

$labName1                            = new StringCustomFieldRef();
$labName1->internalId                = "custevent11"; // internal id of the input in Netsuite
$labName1->value         = "Dealer"; // your input

$labName2                            = new StringCustomFieldRef();
$labName2->internalId                = "custevent14"; // internal id of the input in Netsuite
$labName2->value         = "Residential"; // your input



$customer->customFieldList= new CustomFieldList();
$customer->customFieldList->customField = array($labName1,$labName2,$labName);

    $request = new AddRequest();
    $request->record = $customer;

    $addResponse = $service->add($request);

    if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
        echo "ADD ERROR";
    } else {
        echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
    }

    ?>
```

XML REQUEST:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:relationships_2013_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="urn:messages_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:ns4="ns"><Header>
<passport xsi:type="Passport"><email>xxxxxx@xxxxx.com</email><password>[Content Removed for Security Reasons]</password><account>xxxxx</account><role internalId="3"/></passport></Header>
<Body><add><record xsi:type="Customer"><firstName>Rathi</firstName><lastName>Amit</lastName><companyName>Live2support.com</companyName><phone>123456789</phone><email>xxx@xxxxxx.com</email><customFieldList><customField internalId="custevent11" xsi:type="StringCustomFieldRef"><value>[Content Removed for Security Reasons]</value></customField><customField internalId="custevent14" xsi:type="StringCustomFieldRef"><value>[Content Removed for Security Reasons]</value></customField><customField internalId="custevent12" xsi:type="StringCustomFieldRef"><value>[Content Removed for Security Reasons]</value></customField></customFieldList></record></add></Body></Envelope>
```

Response:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header><platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_3434906_10312013233905655255582218_d18e16e7454b3</platformMsgs:nsId></platformMsgs:documentInfo></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><addResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
<writeResponse>
<platformCore:status isSuccess="false" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
<platformCore:code>USER_ERROR</platformCore:code>
<platformCore:message>Please enter value(s) for: Business Type, Customer Market, Regions</platformCore:message>
</platformCore:statusDetail></platformCore:status></writeResponse></addResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These custom fields must be defined as mandatory fields. Provide the values for these custom fields using

```
$customer->customFieldList->customField = array();
```

See sample here for help https://github.com/TribeHR/NetSuite-PHP-Client/blob/master/samples/add_with_multiple_custom_fields.php

Comment: Hi @Saqib ,
 
Thanks for your help. I updated some more codes in **above question** as per your answer. Please check and suggest.

Thanks

Comment: @user1376613 What response are you getting now after the change?

Comment: `<platformCore:code>USER_ERROR</platformCore:code>
<platformCore:message>Please enter value(s) for: Business Type, Customer Market, Regions</platformCore:message>
</platformCore:statusDetail>` @Saqib I already edited the above question. Thanks

Comment: @user1376613 Please verify that you have picked the correct internal ids of the custom fields.

Comment: **Now getting error :** 

@Saqib `You do not have permissions to set a value for element entityid due to one of the following reasons: 1) The field is read-only; 2) An associated feature is disabled; 3) The field is available either when a record is created or updated, but not in both cases.`

Please Suggest

Comment: In case of such errors try to do the same thing using the Netsuite UI. Usually these are permission or validation issues.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support @Saqib. Problem solved by passing 
===
$p = new Preferences();
$p->ignoreReadOnlyFields = true;
$service->addHeader("preferences", $p);

Answer (score 0):

The internal IDs for your custom fields look a little suspect.

Custom fields for customers should be "custentityXXXXXXX", where XXXXXXX is the name given to your field.

Also, it's a good idea to name your custom fields something that makes sense. In the UI, in the ID field, you should enter values such as "_business_type".  NetSuite will pre-pend the "custentity" to this, for an ID of "custentity_business_type".  This makes much more sense for you as a programmer, and will keep you from constantly having to figure out which field contains the data you are looking for.